# solve gcd $n^3+3n^2-5$ and $n+2$ with bezout

Tags: arithmetic

Hello I have to solve  $\gcd (n^3+3n^2-5 , n+2)$ with bezout

Here’s how I did it:

bezout says $a$ and $b$ are co prime if and only if $au+bv = 1$.

Then I did :
$(n+2)(n^2+n-2) -(n^3+3n^2-5)$

I found one so their $\gcd$ is equal to $1$.

Did I get the right method ?

Sorry for my bad english !!!

Comment: It seems you did well.

Comment: Okay thanks for your comment it helps me a lot

Comment: You don't need Bezout, Euclid is enough.

Comment: But @YvesDaoust bezout work ?

Comment: You asked "Did I get the right method ?".

Comment: yes but also if it's good like have I solve the problem ? @YvesDaoust

Comment: $(n+2)(n^2+n-2) -(n^3+3n^2-5)=1$ is what the extended Euclidean algorithm gives in $\mathbb Q[n]$ as a polynomial ring: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomialextendedgcd%5Bn%5E3%2B3n%5E2-5%2Cn%2B2%2Cn%5D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A(n^3+3n^2-5) + B(n+2) = 1$$

This isn't a blueprint for a general method of finding a solution. I am going to take advantage of the fact that the second polynomial is $n+2$, a first degree polynomial.

Let $m = n+2$. Then

$$n^3+3n^2-5 = (m-2)^3+3(m-2)^2-5 = m^3 - 3m^2 -1$$

So we need to solve

$$A(m^3 - 3m^2 -1) + B(m) = 1$$

If we let $A=-1$, we get

\begin{align}
   A(m^3 - 3m^2 -1) + B(m) &= 1 \\
   -1(m^3 - 3m^2 -1) + B(m) &= 1 \\
   Bm &= m^3 -3m^2 \\
   B &= m^2 - 3m \\
   B &= (n+2)^2-3(n+2) \\
   B &= n^2 + n - 2
\end{align}

It is easy to check that

$$A(n^2 + n - 2) + B(n+2) = (-1)(n^3+3n^2-5) + (n^2 + n - 2)(n+2) = 1 $$

Comment: Thank you for your explanations this helped me a lot despite having taken time to understand.